# How to Mark-up a 3 pane page in HTML 5

Tags: html

Wanted some advise on how to mark-up in **HTML-5** a `3 pane-page` that would be something like this:

`________________________________________
| Nav Pane  | Content Pane | Info Pane |
________________________________________`

So I figure this would be my basic layout:

```
<aside id="nav">
   <nav></nav>
</aside>
<section id="content"></section>
<aside id="info"></aside>
```

But if I want to then display them the section side by side I would need to create a wrapper to hold the `3 elements`, but I'm not sure what would be a valid **HTML-5** element to use, the obvious is just to create a `div` to hold them:

```
<div>
   <aside id="nav">
      <nav></nav>
   </aside>
   <section id="content"></section>
   <aside id="info"></aside>    
</div>
```

but that feels like a cheat.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I find that wrapping it within a div is fine. Basic structure could be header->content->footer, and inside the content adding those aside and section tags. thats my opinion

Answer (score 0):

You can use header wrapper for nav & section for rest of the two.

```
<header>
    <nav class="nav">
    </nav>
</header>
<section class="content"></section>
<section class="info"></section>
```

There is specific purpose of using **aside**.
You can use **aside** wrapper for info if it is related to content or something other.